# SQL Hive - How to convert Unix Time GREGORIAN DATE to HIJRI DATE

Tags: sql, database, hive

I need help to convert unix time Gregorian date to Hijri Date. I couldn’t find a way that work with HIVE.

The below query is to find the Gregorian date from a unix time column:

`SELECT from_unixtime(time,”yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm”) as Date_t FROM table`